# Root file location $karaf_home after moving karaf server

Tags: karaf

I have had to change the location for our Apache Karaf installation. After the change, several of the configuration settings still point to the original $karaf_home/karaf.base location. I have looked through all the config file and cannot find how this root karaf_home/karaf.base is being set. Any idea how this variable is being set?

Answer (score 0):

One or more bundles in your cache might be still pointing your old karaf location. To make sure just shutdown your karaf, delete everything under your $KARAF_HOME/data/cache and start your karaf again by using "karaf clean" command.