# Karaf configuration

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

When installing karaf in one computer and shifting it to another, lot of base directories have deafult path made during installation.
how to change the variables KARAF_BASE, KARAF_ETC, KARAF_DATA in karaf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020595/root-file-location-karaf-home-after-moving-karaf-server

Comment: which version of karaf do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your `karaf–folder/bin/setenv(.bat/.sh)`

Answer (score 0):

In **karaf–folder/bin/karaf.bat**, you can override these variables.

Example:

```
-Dkaraf.etc="%KARAF_HOME%\..."
```

Note: you can also customize the KARAF_HOME variable at the begin of the karaf.bat script.

Answer (score 0):

You can change **KARAF** environment variables in **bin/setenv** Unix script .